# Apple Music offline files still there if subscription stops after free trial?

Tags: apple-music

I am now using the 3-month free trial of Apple Music. Yesterday, I downloaded a few albums into my iPhone. If I do not join the subscription after the free trial period, will the songs still be in my iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - as Apple says [here](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204839#offline)

> *You can save music offline on up to 10 devices. These songs are accessible only during your Apple Music membership.

Note that you do not need to 'join the subscription after the free trial period', Apple will just start charging your credit card for the subscription.

The point of offline files is so that you can listen to Apple Music without using up your mobile data usage, not to download music to keep forever.

Comment: It does not specify if it will erase it from your device or just won't allow you to play them back after you end your subscription.

Comment: When you say "The point of offline files is so that you can listen to Apple Music without using up your mobile data usage..", that means I would still need to have some form of internet connection to play music "offline"? That would explain why Apple Music stops working after 10 minutes of no data and no wifi.